# Linear Algebra subspace questions

Tags: linear-algebra

These are my two questions! I don't even know how to set up these two questions!

> For each of the following problems, is $\mathcal{W}$ a subspace of the
>   given vector space $V$ over the given scalar field $\mathbb{F}$?
>   Explain your reasoning!
>
> $$(a)\quad V = \mathbb{P, \ F = R},\  \mathcal{W}=\{ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d:\quad c + d = a + b\}$$
>
> $$\text{($\mathbb{P}$ is the vector space for all polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$)}.$$
>
> $$(b)\quad V = \mathbb{R^3, F =R}, \mathcal{W} = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ z\\\end{bmatrix} : 3x + 5y + 4z - 3 = 0\right\} $$

Comment: Is something missing?

Comment: There are two operations defined on a vector space and one distinguished element. So, given a subset of a vector space, you have to show that it is closed under both operations (and you will automatically get alignment of distinguished elements).

Comment: @peoplepower I am still not following :/

Answer (score 3):

In general, given a vector space $V$ and a subset $W$, $W$ is a subspace of $V$ provided 1) $W$ is not empty, and 2) for all $p$ and $q$ in $W$, and all real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\alpha p+\beta q$ is in $W$.

So, in (a), first show $W$ is not empty, then let $p$ and $q$ be typical elements of $W$, let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be real numbers, and see if you can prove that $\alpha p+\beta q$ is in $W$.

(b) is a bit easier --- there is one element that is guaranteed to be in every vector space, and you should know what that element is, and you should be able to tell whether it's in $W$.

Answer (score 1):

**For (a):**

Let v1 and v2 belong to **V**, such that 
$$
v_k = a_k x^3 + b_kx^2 + c_kx + d_k;\space    k=1,2 \\ 
a_k + b_k - c_k - d_k = 0 
$$

let α and β belong to **R**, such that
$$
v_3= \alpha v_1+\beta v_2 = \alpha (a_1x^3+b_1x^2+c_1x+d_1)+\beta (a_2x^3+b_2x^2+c_2x+d_2)\\ = (\alpha a_1+\beta a_2)x^3+(\alpha b_1+\beta b_2)x^2+(\alpha c_1 + \beta c_2)x+(\alpha d_1 + \beta d_2) \\
= a_3x^3 + b_3x^2 + c_3x + d
$$
$$
a_3+b_3 -c_3-d_3=(\alpha a_1 + \beta a_2) + (\alpha b_1 + \beta b_2) - (\alpha c_1 + \beta c_2) - (\alpha d_1 + \beta d_2) \\= \alpha (a_1 + b_1 - c_1 - d_1) + \beta (a_2 + b_2 - c_2 - d_2) = 0
$$
Since a3+b3=c3+d3, αv1 + βv2 also belongs to **V**. This set has closure under both binary operations.
Also, zero is obviously in the set:

$$0 = 0x^3 + 0x^2 + 0x + 0\\
a+b-c-d = 0$$

Therefore this is a valid subspace.

**For (b):**

Let v1 and v2 belong to **V**, such that
$$ v_k = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_k \\
    y_k \\
    z_k       
\end{bmatrix}; \space k=1,2
\\ 3x_k + 5y_k + 4z_k - 3 = 0
\\
\\
\\
$$
$$
v_3=v_1 + v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 + x_2 \\
    y_1 + y_2\\
    z_1 + z_2      
\end{bmatrix}
\\
3x_3+5y_3+4z_3-3=\\3(x_1+x_2)+5(y_1+y_2)+4(z_1+z_2)-3 = \\ 3x_1 + 5y_1 + 4z_1 + (3x_2+5y_2+4z_2-3) = 3x_1 + 5y_1 + 4z_1 + 0 = 3x_1 + 5y_1 + 4z_1 \neq 0 (generally)
$$

This set is not closed under addition, so it cannot be a valid subspace.